# VSCode Comment Multiple Lines Individually

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an option (or extension) in VSCode to comment multiple selected lines individually and not as a block-comment?

Currently if I select multiple lines and press Cmd + /  It comments the section as a block. The problem is, if I later want to uncomment just a particular line from that block I have to uncomment the entire block and then comment the other lines individually.

It seems something pretty common to do. But can't find a setting in VSCode to do this. I believe Jetbrain's Webstorm IDE have that option.

Comment: I wrote the extension `Toggle Line Comments` https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments does that.

Comment: What language are you in? Cmd+/ toggles the line comments individually in js for me already.

Comment: use **Multi Cursor** to place a cursor on each line of the block and the `Cmd+/` (`Ctrl+/`), use `Esc` to get out of Multi Cursor

Comment: if this is about HTML, then yeah, I can reproduce what you're seeing. in that case, then use multi-cursor editing to create multiple cursors on each line that you want to individually comment and then invoke the line comment command / keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thank you. I'm primary using JSX. @Mark extension seems to do the Job.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour on Ubuntu with a JSX file and using `ctrl+/`. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.